# Setting detail levels in the C# wrapper for the Gracenote Web API

Tags: c#, gracenote

I am currently working with the Gracenote Web API using the C# wrapper made by [Park Square](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3592281/parksq) and I don't know how to set the detail levels.

Currently the Search() method only returns one level of detail for genre, mood, tempo etc. but I would like to get as much detail as possible.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var gnRes = gnClient.Search(new SearchCriteria {
    AlbumTitle = albumName,
    Artist = artistName,
    TrackTitle = trackTitle,
    SearchMode = SearchMode.BestMatchWithCoverArt,
    SearchOptions = SearchOptions.Mood | SearchOptions.Tempo | SearchOptions.ArtistOriginEraType
});
```

I have discovered that the SearchCriteria object has a ResponseDetail class indicating that it is indeed possible to set the detail level but I don't know how to use it correctly. The doumentation posted for the wrapper doesn't mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this and get the type of response I want.

```
        SearchCriteria searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria();
        ResponseDetail detail = new ResponseDetail();

        detail.GenreLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Three;
        detail.MoodLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Two;
        detail.TempoLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Three;
        detail.ArtistEraLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Two;
        detail.ArtistOriginLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Four;
        detail.ArtistTypeLevels = ResponseDetail.Level.Two;

        searchCriteria.AlbumTitle = albumTitle;
        searchCriteria.Artist = artistName;
        searchCriteria.TrackTitle = trackTitle;

        searchCriteria.SearchMode = SearchMode.BestMatch;
        searchCriteria.SearchOptions = SearchOptions.Mood | SearchOptions.Tempo | SearchOptions.ArtistOriginEraType;
        searchCriteria.ResponseDetail = detail;

        SearchResult gnRes = gnClient.Search(searchCriteria);
```